# How to change the name of variables in R based on the first three letter of the country

Tags: r

I have a large time-series data with more than 20 variables. The name of these variables starts with `P_`. For example, `P_Australia`. I would like to change the name of all these variables, to take only the first three letters of each country. For example, I would like to have like this: `P_Aus`. How to do this automatically in R. I read the similar solution suggestions by the website, but it is different from what I expected.

Suppose my data is like this:

`P_Australia`, `P_Canada`, `P_Japan`.

I need to have like this:

`P_Aus`, `P_Can`, `P_Jap`.

Any help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just select the first 5 letters of every name by using substring:

```
names(df) = substr(names(df),1,5)
```

This shortens your variable names to their first 5 letters.